# Microsof office 365 excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

I am trying to create a function that will take multiple inputs (cells) and output into one cell.

Cells `B9`, `B10`, `B11`, and `B12` all have different numerical inputs. I would like to use 4 different equations (`B9 input = B9 output`, `B10 input = B10/12000 output`, `B11 input = B11/12 output`, `B12 input = B12/400`. I would like the output cell would be `E9` for all inputs. i.e., with any of the 4 inputs, you can calculate the 1 output.

I have done this with some success with two inputs by using the `=IF` statement:

```
=IF(VALUE(B9),(B9),IF(VALUE(B12),B12/400))
```

I have also gotten a "True" output in my cell by using the formula below. The issue with this, is that I am looking to get the values calculated (not a true/false output).

```
=OR(VALUE(B9),(B9),VALUE(B10),(B10/12000),VALUE(B11),(B11/12),VALUE(B12),B12/400)
```

These are some common calculations used for the HVAC industry. My B9 input is "Tons." You can calculate 1 Ton = 1 Ton, 12,000 BTUH, 12 MBH, or 400 CFM. So, in this case my four output cells would be: Tons, BTUH, MBH, CFM

My current spreadsheet does not have any way to ensure that there is only one input.  I am the only user, so that should not be an issue of having more than one input variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IFS:

```
=IFS(B9>0,B9,B10>0,B1/12000,B11>0,B11/12,B12>0,B12/400,TRUE,"")
```